# Initialize a XAML object's collection

Tags: xaml, collections, initialization

When trying to define an object's collection, project doesn't build anymore and the following errors are raised:

- The property "dboForeignReleaseIds" can only be set once.
- The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "IList`1".

How do you initalize an object's collection in XAML ?

I've followed the same pattern as Blend does when creating sample data from a class, you might ask why I don't use it then ? Because it's only available at design time, not run-time.

```
<echoNestModel:dboTrackProfile x:Key="dboTrackProfile"
                                        Title="El Amor"
                                        AnalyzerVersion="3.13"
                                        Artist="Joeski"
                                        ArtistId="4564123113"
                                        AudioMd5="HJK34YKUGH34J3"
                                        Bitrate="320"
                                        PreviewUrl="http:\\www.echonest.com"
                                        Release="El Amor Remixes"
                                        ReleaseImage="image"
                                        Samplerate="44100"
                                        SongId="4U623784Y2HJ"
                                        Status="OK"
                                        dboId="19">
    <!-- errors from here -->
    <echoNestModel:dboTrackProfile.dboForeignReleaseIds>
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="54" Value="Rutrum vivamus sapien tristique" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="70" Value="Parturient vestibulum" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="71" Value="Sed aliquam ultricies morbi vestibulum" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="69" Value="Adipiscing senectus sociosqu aliquet parturient" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="43" Value="Suscipit sem" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="25" Value="Torquent sit" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="23" Value="Semper venenatis" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="16" Value="Blandit vulputate vel vestibulum ultrices" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="29" Value="Vehicula erat volutpat nulla" />
        <echoNestModel:dboForeignReleaseId dboId="30" Value="Eros maecenas nibh curabitur proin" />
    </echoNestModel:dboTrackProfile.dboForeignReleaseIds>
    <!-- to here -->
</echoNestModel:dboTrackProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was that the property (generated by OpenAccess ORM) did not have a setter.